# what does the Square brackets before a class declaration mean?

Tags: scala, class, definition, brackets

the scala class is declared as below:

```
private[kafka] abstract class AbstractServerThread(connectionQuotas: ConnectionQuotas) extends Runnable with Logging { 
  ....
}
```

I don't know what's the meaning of `[]`.

Anyone could give me the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means that this class is private to the `kafka` package (can only be accessed from within that package).